# Laravel: Advanced Polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I am attempting to scope an answer to a `User` or `Project` via a polymorphic relationship via multiple levels but I am having some trouble getting my head around it.

It's tricky to explain, but I will show you what I have at the moment, minus the `Answer` model/relationship.

- I have a `Category` and a `Role` model. These are in a `belongsTo` relationship (a role belongs to a category).
- I also have a `Question` model, this also has a `belongsTo` relationship with a `Role` (a question belongs to a role).
- I have created a `roleables` polymorphic relationship, allowing me to assign roles to either a `User` or a `Project`.

All of this is working as expected. I am able to return the assigned roles via my endpoint `user/1/roles` or `project/1/roles`, and in this endpoint, I am able to return the questions for that role (see example output below).

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Actor",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "category_id": 3,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "role_id": 20,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Height",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:5",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "role_id": 20,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Weight",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:5",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "role_id": 20,
                    "field_type": "select",
                    "field_name": "Race",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": [
                        {
                            "id": "white",
                            "name": "White"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "mixed",
                            "name": "Mixed"
                        }
                    ],
                    "order": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 23,
                    "role_id": 20,
                    "field_type": "select",
                    "field_name": "Gender",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": [
                        {
                            "id": "male",
                            "name": "Male"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "female",
                            "name": "Female"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "other",
                            "name": "Other"
                        }
                    ],
                    "order": 3
                }
            ],
            "created_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "entity_type": "user"
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "Singer",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "category_id": 3,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 26,
                    "role_id": 23,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Description",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 0
                }
            ],
            "created_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "entity_type": "user"
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "name": "Console Operator",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "category_id": 5,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 35,
                    "role_id": 32,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Description",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 0
                }
            ],
            "created_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "entity_type": "user"
        },
        {
            "id": 60,
            "name": "Composer",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "category_id": 7,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 63,
                    "role_id": 60,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Description",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 0
                }
            ],
            "created_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "entity_type": "user"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem that I am trying to get my head around is `Answers` to the questions. Just a little background, which may help me explain this in writing:

*In the front-end, I have a page in which the user can update their information, on this page they also have the ability to assign themselves some roles. When the click on a role the list of questions is displayed and they have the ability to answer them.*

*The same is also true for a Project. A user can create projects, and have the ability to assigned roles and answer the relevant questions.*

So, I guess I will need to create a new table in the database to store the answers.

The question is how/what relationship should this new answers table have to the question, user/project in order to get all the roles, questions and any answers scoped to the entity (user/project) and it's roles?

I would love the each role in the output from my `user/1/role`endpoint to look more like the following (notice the new answers key in questions):

```
{
            "id": 60,
            "name": "Composer",
            "entity_id": 1,
            "category_id": 7,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 63,
                    "role_id": 60,
                    "field_type": "text",
                    "field_name": "Description",
                    "field_default_value": null,
                    "field_validation_rules": "required,string,max:255",
                    "field_options": false,
                    "order": 0,
                    "answers": { ... }
                }
            ],
            "created_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2019-07-24 13:35:33.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            },
            "entity_type": "user"
        }
```

Comment: Is it returning all the answers for a question or none at all?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far, I am currently just trying to wrap my head around the relationship type I would need and the database structure.

Comment: Is this going to be for a single user?

Comment: Each registered user in the system can have roles assigned, they then have the ability to answer questions depending on the role they selected. This also needs to be flexible enough so that I can also assign roles->questions->answers on to a project too.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I get that. What I meant was when you're getting/displaying the information is it going to be for one user at a time or are you going to be retrieving multiple users at the same time. Also, can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. 

I don't have any code to show really as that is question, how should I structure my relationships to achieve what I need. 

I could be retrieving multiple users at the same time. I think the real issue here is how to get my answers scoped to a user's roles as well as the question that belongs to the role.

Comment: @Rwd I have updated my question to hopefully explain a little better and with some added background.